# Ubuntu 16.04 field separator / column separator / delimiter setting

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

in Windows there is "list separator" settings in regional settings. As far as I know, that is a setting to change field/column separator. But I can't find a similar setting in Ubuntu 16.04. Please help me, find that kind of setting in Ubuntu? I need to change delimiter in Ubuntu to a semicolon. Thank you.